# How to count how often the circuit breaker changed its state from closed to open?

Tags: java, hystrix

Is there a way to find out how often the Hystrix circuit breaker changed its state from *closed* to *open*? I'd expect something like

```
HystrixCommandMetrics m = ...; 
long count = m.getCumulativeCount(HystrixEventType.SHORT_CIRCUITED);
```

But this counts the number of command executions that failed while the circuit breaker is open. It does not count the state change itself.

Comment: @ryyker please explain how this could help.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit breaker itself doesn't provide metrics, it only uses the metrics to inform its transition between CLOSED, HALF_OPEN, and OPEN.

You could keep your own count of open vs. closed transitions by creating your own subscriber for the metrics stream. You just have to keep track of the last known state  of the circuit, and when you get an update from the stream, compare the last know state with the one in the update. If they're different, then a transition has occurred and you would update your own counter.

In 1.4 you have to use `new HystrixMetricsPoller()`, and pass it your own implementation of `MetricsAsJsonPollerListener` that parses the provided JSON for `isCircuitOpen` for each command.

In 1.5 you would use `HystrixDashboardStream.getInstance().observe()` and register your own consumer to get updates. I think this approach is a little more effort to get at the underlying `HystrixCircuitBreaker` object for each command, which is what would let you check `isOpen()` to get the current state of each circuit breaker.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a method similar to the one you show is native to Hystrix, although one could probably be created by understanding the *Hystrix* way of determining whether a circuit breaker were opened or closed.

The flowchart *[here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Netflix/Hystrix/images/hystrix-command-flow-chart.png])* provides an illustration of the details of how it works. ( *[These pages](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#flow8)* detail the flowchart )  One of the details specifically addresses *[Is the Circuit Open?](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-it-Works#4-is-the-circuit-open)*.

Excerpt from *Is the Circuit Open?*

> When you execute the command, Hystrix checks with the circuit-breaker
>   to see if the circuit is open.
>
> If the circuit is open (or “tripped”) then Hystrix will not execute
>   the command but will route the flow to (8) Get the Fallback.
>
> If the circuit is closed then the flow proceeds to (5) to check if
>   there is capacity available to run the command.

By recognizing this behavior then, detecting when state changes from Closed to Open is possible.

From *[this page](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring)* is a concise list of Hystrix event types.  The one flagged will be useful in the steps referenced above:  [image]